# Auto-Mounting Samba Server Shares with GUI Shortcuts

Tags: networking, fstab, ubuntu-gnome, automount, samba4

I've referenced this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050460/how-to-mount-smb-share-on-ubuntu-18-04), this [other one](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently), that [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191186/mounting-samba-shares-at-boot-login-and-using-script), this [page](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/automatically-mount-network-shares-on-linux/) and the man which have aided me greatly in allowing for automatic mounting of Samba shares from a remote server on my LAN to my local Ubuntu 18.04 machine with GNOME GUI.

The steps I've followed are as follows:

1) Created a mounting point on the local system by

> ~$ sudo mkdir /media/HHAdmin

2) Created a secure Samba credentials file for login information by

> ~$ sudo gedit ~/.smbcredentials
>
> ~$ chmod 600 ~/.smbcredentials

3) Backed up and appended Samba share details in fstab by

> ~$ sudo su -
>
> ~# cp /etc/fstab fstab.old
>
> ~# gedit /etc/fstab
>
> appended fstab to include:
>
> //192.168.1.4/HHAdmin /media/HH-Admin cifs x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=3,uid=1000,gid=1000,credentials=/home/hannah/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8 0 0

4) Exited root login and tested mount by

> ~# exit
>
> ~$ sudo mount -a
>
> success
>
> sudo reboot now

## SUCCESS!

After the system reboots and I log into hannah, there are two icons on the GNOME desktop; one icon resembles a traditional folder with a network plug and the other icon resembles a HDD/USB media drive.  Both work to take me to the share.

My question is, how can I remove or hide the second icon (the HDD/USB icon) on the desktop leaving just one icon to access the share from the desktop?

[fig 1 - The two icons I'm referring to...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZijU5.png)

Thanks all!

carvio

P.S.  This is my first post on this forum and one of my first attempts at customizing my Ubuntu.  If you have any critiques of my technique in the code samples posted above, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the gigolo package using Synaptic or "Software Manager" (or just use the command `sudo apt install gigolo` on your Debian based distro. It's nice if you don't want to do manual scripting (more MS windowsOS like). If you have it auto connect and startup on your profile it feels more like saved network places in MS Windows OS's. Project home page https://www.uvena.de/gigolo/ for details.

Comment: Please be a little careful about using Copy and Paste answers across Ask Ubuntu particularly when you are giving a link to a particular application...